# Atualizações e melhorias do portal

Tags: suporte

Existe alguma parte do portal, que mostre as alterações realizadas (atualizações, correções, melhorias, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em português não, mas há [este post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305560/208518) onde a equipa responsável por melhorar o software de perguntas e respostas, etc., faz os seus updates mensais em inglês.